# Controlling the behavior of table cellspacing in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there something we can do like table[cellspacing=x] that allows us to control the td margin with the variable x?

I ask this because in my setup, I am using a reset stylesheet that has a definition:

```
table {
   border-collapse:separate;
   border-spacing:2px;
   ...
}
```

This works fine until the we encounter a line in the html as such:

```
<table cellspacing=5>
```

...

Basically, I want to be able to define the behavior for cellspacing in my reset stylesheet...

Is this possible with CSS?

---

## Update:

Well, actually, let me be more clear about my problem:

I am working with a templated system that uses a reset style on the bottom.

Any random user can come along and create HTML content on top of that, possibly containing a table something like this:

```
<table cellspacing=7>
```

I want to override the default styling behavior of all browsers with my own styling behavior, when it comes to handling the cellspacing attribute of the table element.

The number passed to the cellspacing attribute will be unknown to me, as the system is dynamic.

I need to be able to control the behavior of cellspacing using CSS in the reset stylesheet to accomplish this, or else whatever some end-user types in for cellspacing in their hypothetical table will be overridden by this line in my reset stylesheet:

```
table {
   border-collapse:separate;
   border-spacing:2px;
   ...
}
```

So, I need a statement that will work with whatever value the end-user passes to the cellspacing attribute.

I'd imagine this statement looks something like:

```
table[cellspacing=x] > td {
   ...
}
```

Such that I can use the variable x in the body of this CSS definition.

You see, I can't just use a static value like 3, or 5, or 10 for cellspacing because the value the user puts in will be unknown to me when I am making my reset stylesheet. They can put in whatever they want, but it will always use the same reset stylesheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should have edited your update into your question. I've done this for you, and removed your "answer". I've also added another answer of my own to your question to answer your update.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
table[cellspacing="5"] {
    border-spacing: 30px;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/k2Qpt/

This uses the [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector).

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding properties to accomplish this from css.

```css
table td {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:25px;
}
```

The above will put cell spacing of 25px on the right side of each cell and 10px on the bottom of each cell. I literally did this today in my own project :)

Comment: I actually may have misunderstood your question. Any inline css will overwrite whatever is in your stylesheet. You will need to remove it from being inline. For example, remove cellspacing=5 from <table cellspacing=5>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thirtydot understand the question... the code should be:

```
table.spaced td {
    padding:5px;
}
```

if you want only tables with the class spaced to have cellspacing.

if you want every table to have cellspacing:

```
table td {
    padding:5px;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/ben7005/3w4EU/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your update:

I've had a thorough think about this. What would be nice is if you could do:

```
table[cellspacing] {
    border-spacing: auto;
}
```

That *would* override your `border-spacing: 2px`. But, this won't work because there is no `auto` or `normal` value that you can set `border-spacing` to :(

If you only need to support modern browsers, you can use:

```
table:not([cellspacing]) {
    border-spacing: 20px;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/7YUYs/

That will only select `table`s that don't have `cellspacing` set.

Browser support for the `:not` selector is reasonable, except that it doesn't work in IE until version 9:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/:not

To make it work in older versions of IE, you could use: http://selectivizr.com/

If that's not an option, I think the only choice that doesn't require using JavaScript is to do this:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 2px
}

table[cellspacing="0"] { border-spacing: 0 }
table[cellspacing="1"] { border-spacing: 1px }
table[cellspacing="2"] { border-spacing: 2px }
table[cellspacing="3"] { border-spacing: 3px }
..
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/UJasP/

All `table`s will have `border-spacing: 2px`, but any `table`s with `cellspacing` set will have `border-spacing` set to the correct value. You should go as high with the numbers as you think you need to - the size of your CSS file is not a problem.

Comment: @Keoki Zee: I could have done that, but this answer is so very different from my other one (because of the update to the question) that I don't think it should have a bunch of upvotes from people who haven't even seen it. It needs to be judged on its own merit.